# Doubt about verb - "gives to me"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> "The pen which my friend **gives to me** is black"

Actually I have two questions regarding this:
1. Is the verb in this tense ok to use?
2. Is 'to' ok to use?

Comment: The present tense is only appropriate here if you are describing the action as it happens - "My friend walks up to me and hands me a pen. The pen which he gives to me is black." - or if your friend presents you with a black pen every week.

Answer (score 1):

*Give* is the canonical English verb licensing an **indirect object**:

> My friend gives **me** a pen.

A review of of several corpora of English texts finds occurrences of the *prepositional phrase* with a preposition of transfer, as in

> My friend gives *to me* a pen.

But the latter is disfavored by a large margin, on the order of hundreds of times less likely. Many of these appear in archaic legalistic language like that in old wills:

> I *give unto my friend* my favorite pen

or in religious tracts, probably influenced by Bible translations. Compare *Revelation* 22:1

> I will *give unto him* that is athirst of the fountain of the water of life freely.

In informal writing, you're probably better off using the indirect object.

Comment: When *give* licenses a direct object, it also licenses a PP, but the usual order is as in this example: *They gave a prize to the best chef* (from https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/give, where they also put it pretty explicitly: "Don’t say 'give to someone something'").